# When I use the Integer.parseInt() function it shows me error when I put 1 on the Textfield

Tags: java, integer

[image: StackTrace]

I made the project, but in some conditions the compiler shows the error I've provided above. Would someone be able to help me to investigate it?

Comment: You need to check out for the token array values. Add breakpoint there and debug those line. You also not provided code which sets value of `line` String object.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that "**serialNumberQuantity.getText()**" in returning empty string (""). You should debug if the value is getting over ridden by some condition in your code.

Comment: Or the code is on another instance of the TextField, or is called for an other event earlier: when the text field is added (wrong event handler).